# How to decrypt an encrypted column with the AES method?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, security, encryption

So I have two tables, a `Patient` table with an id `patient_id` and another table `medical_file` with a column `patient`, the `patien_id` encrypted with AES method (not a foreign key). I use *Hibernate* for the ORM, in the **MedicalFile** Entity I use the AES encryption to encrypt the `patient` in the setter method `setPatient` and the decryption in the getter method `getPatient` to decrypt the value that fetched from the database. The code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient", schema = "public")
public class Patient extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator  = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
//....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "medical_file", schema = "public")
public class MedicalFile extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "patient")
    private String patient;
//...

    public void setPatient(String patient) {
        AES256TextEncryptor textEncryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
        textEncryptor.setPassword("key");
        this.patient = textEncryptor.encrypt(patient);
    }

    public String getPatient() {
        AES256TextEncryptor textEncryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
        textEncryptor.setPassword("key");
        return textEncryptor.decrypt(patient);
    }
}
```

So when I want to save the `medical_file` table,I have to encrypt the `patient` column, and when I want to get the `medical_file` of a patient, I have decrypt the `patient` column in the 'medical_file' table.

The problem that the AES encryption for the `patient` with the same key differ every time, so when I have the `patient_id` (the same as `patient` in `medical_file` table but not encrypted) and I want to encrypted to get the `patient` from `medical_file` table I got a different value that **doesn't** exist in the `medical_file` table.

Any suggestions to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you care about sensitive data stored in the DB why not just encrypt the whole DB or disk?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, what you are trying to do is -

> you are storing the AES encrypted data in a table and then want to
>   retrieve it based on encrypted data again, but the problem is that
>   every AES encryption is generating a different value and you are not
>   possible to mind a match in DB.

What I will suggest it to put on more column of **MD5 hash** along with other **AES** encrypted data. MD5 is **irreversible** but it will generate **same** value for same input every time (this is what mostly used in storing passwords). So next time when you want to search you have create **MD5 hash** of you input, find it from DB and then **decrypt** rest of the data using **AES decryption**.

Let me know if this is *useful*. *Ignore* my ans if I did **not** get your problem correctly.

Comment: You got it, and It works, but It's not what I want. If someone got access to the database, he can encrypt the patient_id in the patient table to get the data from the medical_file table. My purpose is to decrypt the relation between the two table.

Comment: Yes you are right that anyone can create `MD5 hash` and access data from medical_file table if he knows patient_id, Though you can do `MD5 hash with salt` (which is personal to your code) and will generate a value which any other attacker who gets access to the `medical_file` table wont be able to generate.

Comment: MD5 with salt - https://www.viralpatel.net/java-md5-hashing-salting-password/